# Add Css in JsPDF while generating pdf

Tags: pdf, jspdf

I have been stuck in this for several days .
i have created pdf using jsPDf lib and im trying to css in the created pdf. PDF generated is like this https://prnt.sc/tq9gqx and i want to make pdf like https://prnt.sc/tq9ivi.
Your help will be highly appreciated.

```
<script>
   function demoFromHTML() {
      var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4', true);
      source = $('#content')[0];
      specialElementHandlers = {
         '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
            return true
         }
      };
      margins = {
         top: 80,
         bottom: 60,
         left: 40,
         width: 522
      };
      pdf.fromHTML(
            source,
            margins.left,
            margins.top, {
               // y coord
               'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
               'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
            },
            function (dispose) {
               pdf.save('ticket');
               var pdfBase64 = pdf.output();
               var email= 'check@email.com';
               $.ajax({
                  'url': baseUrl + '/site/email',
                  'method': 'post',
                  'data': {
                     'pdfBase64': pdfBase64,
                     'email':email
                  },
                  'success': function (result) {
                     if (!result == 'true') {
                        notify('Sorry Email NOt sent', 'danger');
                     } else {
                        notify('Ticket sent', 'success');
                     }
                  },
                  'error': function (error) {
                     notify('Server Error. Sorry Email Not Sent', 'danger');
                  }
               });

            }, margins
      );


      // $('#email').val(pdfBase64);
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Where's your code? Please follow the rules to show the effort you've done so far and the issue you're facing.

Comment: should we make the table format of the view file ? to include css?

Answer (score 0):

Don't put style in external files. can you apply your style inline or same file.

Comment: style is in same file still i tried using inline style but nothing changed

Comment: kindly check your HTML structure. if you are using DIV tag it will not working properly. use Table tags. refer this https://jsfiddle.net/elangomsk/khemq5L8/2/

Comment: isn't there any solution to make without changing div to table?